# imperative programing to functional programming using recursion

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm very new to functional programming. I'm struggling using recursion instead of for loop. Here's  what I have so far.

```
let max_factor n = 
  let rec loop k = 
    if k >= n then [] 
    else
      begin
        if k < n && n % k = 0 then
          k :: loop(k+1)
      end
```

my plan is to insert the ones into a list and then find the largest from the list. But I have a feeling I'm doing it wrong. With functional programming, is it always like "going around" or am I just a bad at this? is my approach way off? Can someone please guide me how I should approach this simple problem...

Comment: Why a list? And why does your recursion increment the `k`?

Comment: @Bergi list: because I'm not sure how to return the biggest one right away. it increments k so I can check 1 to n to see which one has the largest factor

Comment: But that's not the simple approach you've chosen in the java loop, where you iterate downwards and just return the first (largest) factor that you find. (Btw, did you mean to `return i` not `return n`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent to your java code would be

```
let max_factor (n : int) : int = 
  let rec loop i = 
    if i < 2 then 1
    else if n mod i = 0 then i
    else loop (i-1)
  in loop (n / 2);; (* you don't want to start at n, which would trivially divide n *)
```

Comment: pardon my ignorance but what does val max_factor : int -> int option do? is it for setting the return value to max_factor? do we have to do : int -> int option??

Comment: also when i compile it, it says "This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         'a option
"

Comment: It was supposed to be the type signature of the function. Sorry, my Ocaml is a bit rusty :-)

Comment: thanks for the update but it says "Wrong type ((int * int) * (int * int)) list."

Comment: @rosababy That error must come from somewhere else in your code then. I've now updated with a version that I actually tried out, it works in the repl

Comment: ok thanks. I think the problem on my side that my test requires int not an int option. but I'm not sure how to replace int option to int....or are they the same thing?

Comment: I really don't understand why the test gives me "Found max_factor with unexpected type:
Wrong type int -> int option.

"

Comment: @rosababy What is your function expected to return when the passed integer is a prime, i.e. has no factor?